# Dialogflow: if condition based on time response

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am making a pizza delivery chatbot and one of the training samples is

Are you open right now?

**PARAMETER NAME      ENTITY          RESOLVED VALUE**

```
time             @sys.time            now
```

One of the responses I want to have is if the time is between 12 am and 6 am , the reponse I coded is :

**{{#if $time> 12:00:00}}I think it is too late{/if}}**

But the response i am getting is :

**{#if 12:00:34> 12:10:00}I think it is too late{/if}**, which is wrong. Can someone help me on how to resolve this.

TIA

Comment: Where, exactly, have you coded these responses? In your fulfillment or in the responses in the UI?

Comment: @Prisoner, in the response section.

Comment: you need to handle those from your fulfilment, console i think is not supporting this kind of template

Answer (score 1):

The Response section has a very very simple templating system - it allows for parameter/value replacement, and that is about it.

So you can [specify a parameter value from an input phrase](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#basic) using something like `$parameter-name`, while [parameter values in a Context or Event](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#context) would be `#context-name.parmaeter-name`. You don't need the `{braces}` to do the evaluation, since those are used to [escape the `$` and `#` as special characters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-responses#special). So if you needed to show "$100", you would write that as `${100}`. If you need the braces to be displayed, you'd include those inside another set of braces, which is why your text seems to get the braces removed.

You will need to put this processing in your fulfillment code. Libraries such as [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) will let you create responses and setup response logic using templates. (Multivocal uses the handlebars templating library, for example.)